# .scss files not compiling .css automatically

Tags: ios, css, node.js, cordova, gulp

I am using `Ionic` and I have a `Gulpfile.js` that worked perfectly before. I updated npm, Angular, Ionic and cordova, which has broken my working environment.

**Right now**, I need to **manually start `ionic serve` (or gulp watch)** so that it recognizes that I make changes in my .scss file and then compiles it to .css

**Before** these updates, I could change my .scss file and it would **automatically** recognize the changes and compile it to .css instead of me triggering `ionic serve` or `gulp watch` *manually* beforehand.

This is what `ionic info` gives me:

> WARN] Error with ./www/lib/ionic/version.json file: FILE_NOT_FOUND,
>   trying ./bower.json.
>
> cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)
>
> ```
> @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.16.0
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.16.0
> ```
>
> global packages:
>
> ```
> cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1 
> Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
> ```
>
> local packages:
>
> ```
> Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0 ios 4.4.0
> Ionic Framework   : ionic1 master
> ```
>
> System:
>
> ```
> ios-deploy : 1.9.0 
> ios-sim    : 5.0.8 
> Node       : v6.8.1
> npm        : 4.6.1 
> OS         : macOS High Sierra
> Xcode      : Xcode 9.1 Build version 9B55
> ```
>
> Environment Variables:
>
> ```
> ANDROID_HOME : not set
> ```
>
> Misc:
>
> ```
> backend : pro
> ```

I am using `xCode` with `cordova prepare ios` to deploy it on the iPhone, but as you can understand, because the .css is not compiled automatically, the app does not recognize the css changes as it can not see them if I don't do it manually.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this seems like it's an `Ionic CLI` problem. After updating to Ionic CLI 3, the `gulp watch` tasks are not being triggered, which gives this annoying problem.

You can see that one of the developers is stating he will fix this.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2859#issuecomment-342338626

**Edit:** it's fixed now. You can fix it by installing the *alpha CLI* via `npm i -g ionic@canary.`